# The number of prime divisors of any number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can one show that the number of prime divisors of any number less than $2^n$ is at most $n$.

Comment: Prove that the smallest natural number divisible by $n$ primes is $2^{n}$. It then follows that there can be no natural numbers less then $2^{n}$ with either $n$ or more prime factors because otherwise that would contradict our first statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** All the prime divisors are $\ge 2$.

**Remark:** As pointed out by Gerry Myerson, a stronger formulation of the question is that the number of prime divisors of a positive integer less than $2^{n+1}$ is at most $n$.